# How do I use SUMPRODUCT to sum based on two criterias?

Tags: excel

I have the following formula which does what i want it to do:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Total Table'!$B$3:$B$935=$G$26),
'Total Table'!$W$3:$W$935,'Total Table'!$Z$3:$Z$935)
```

Which is if G26 appears in the Total Table column B, sum the total sum of column W in the Total Table tab and the Total Percentages in the AE Column in the Total Table tab.

It works.

However, I want to add another criteria, I need G26 to appear in column B in the Total Table tab, but also another value (call it 'FR') to appear in column M in the Total Table tab.

How would one do this? I have tried doing:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Total Table'!$B$3:$B$935=$G$26),('Total Table'!$M$3:$M$935="FR"),
'Total Table'!$W$3:$W$935,'Total Table'!$Z$3:$Z$935)
```

And it isnt working.

Thank you.

Comment: The first two criteria in your formula look to me like they should work. Does it behave any differently if you prefix the second one with `--` as you've done with the first?

Comment: I will give it a go. I have changed my formula to what i originally had as I accidently presented my alterered code!

Comment: Yep, spot on. I just missed the -- :)... thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. If your criterion results in a boolean value, you need to double-negate this using `--` to turn it into a numerical value, otherwise `SUMPRODUCT` will take this value as zero. You've already done this for the first criterion, so you just need to do the same thing for the second:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Total Table'!$B$3:$B$935=$G$26),--('Total Table'!$M$3:$M$935="FR"),'Total Table'!$W$3:$W$935,'Total Table'!$Z$3:$Z$935)
```

Answer (score 1):

ScoutEU could you please try the below formula and tell me what you get?

**Total Table Sheet:**

[image]

**Sheet3:**

[image]

**Formula:**

`=SUMPRODUCT(('Total Table'!$B$3:$B$935=$G$26)*('Total Table'!$M$3:$M$935="FR")*('Total Table'!$Z$3:$Z$935))`

Comment: Hey Error, I get a value error. It is ok though, jsheeran's solution worked for me :)